# SQL altering tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle, tablespace

Okay as I was creating my tables, it gave me the following error:

```
ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'USERS'
```

So I type this command to change the tablespace: `ALTER USER bju5108 quota unlimited on USERS;`

And then it gave me this message: ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege

How should I fix this?

Comment: What user are you executing the command as?

Comment: bju5108 which is my SQL username.

Comment: If you don't have sufficient privileges, you may need to call your Database Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `ALTER USER bju5108 quota unlimited on USERS;` as system or sysdba.

Comment: `conn / as sysdba` or `conn system/<system password>`

Answer (score 2):

If you have DBA access to the database, then you can fix it by increasing the limit. (by connecting as SYSDBA, example ' sqlplus "connect sys/pass as sysdba"' run in unix.)
like @mmmmmpie said:

```
alter user bju5108 quota unlimited on users;
```

or

```
alter user bju5108 quota 500M on users;  --where 500M should be more then you have now.
```

If you do not, then you need to send a request to your Database Admin (DBA).  This is a restriction issue that users have no control over.